# How can I add a set featured image function to a theme that doesn't already have it built in?

Tags: themes, wp-admin, post-thumbnails

I'm a relative newbie to WP and PHP in general, but now that I'm into it, I've caught the "WP fever" and have ditched asp.net.

I finally found a quality theme that I like and I'm considering buying it; I have 4 blogs and counting, but I can't get the basic version of the theme to display the **set featured image** link in my WP admin when creating a post or page.  Vanilla install, WP 3.5.1.

The support forum isn't that good, and nobody's responded, but I'm quite sure they didn't build this function into their theme.

Is it possible to add the **set featured image** function myself, even if I'm not a PHP junkie (yet)?  Any guidance in this regard (whether I wanna hear it or not!) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can add this line to your `functions.php` file to add the post thumbnail option to all post types:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

If you want it for only one post type, you pass an array of post type names as second argument:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) ); #shown in posts only
```

To display the thumbnail in your template files:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

Read about [Post Thumbails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) and [add_theme_support()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support).

Comment: Hi rrikesh.  Thank you for the time in reading and responding to my question!  The functions.php in my theme seems to be encoded; it's just a bunch of numbers and characters that make no sense.  But I think this will provide me with some direction.  Thanks again for sharing the information, and I'll be reading those links right now!

Comment: Encoded? Are you using a legitimate theme? It might be some backdoor stuff that can be used to gain unauthorized access to your website.

Comment: Well, yes ... it's the Flexibility3 theme ... a lot of people use it.  But it looks like this: <?php 
$QD441FA06E336C09E3C75F4CDE5E7CB88="eNptmU2XqjCXhX/SS0BqXQc9KIWAaEIR8gGZAXEVkoCUWor8+j7Vg+5Jj+6qW1ZIcs7Z+9kSFdfn8ds7MhUOrc9cd/n8OMS45F6/O+DdQSTyt/a3VleHbzPK9+nyuZyGeImKuWLi8J1fdleTsld++ffskv6l/3edsO/G7bUuw7V5/6P7y/UZFdf/fA2v//x97vDpHU/vK93b/1sf1toJuz0U5a4o8c61I33qRL4PqYb1Nt+k3Cyk8I7Sk/tDdP1uUuZ10fV5CnbX7v/2+VtX2bNJ4t ..... and so on; the entire functions.php is like that.  hehe ... I'm sure there's still gotta be a way, though ...

Comment: downloaded from http://www.flexibilitytheme.com/ ? If yes, use at your own risk.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Yes, from that website.  So that's not a respected theme?  Surely the guy who made it doesn't use his own support forum.  I've only seen one post by him in the last 2 years, although there are hundreds of questions.  I just liked the aesthetics of it.  But would you suggest I use another theme?  Any suggestions would be appreciated!  Thanks again rrikesh!

Comment: Never use a anything that has hidden or obfuscated codes in it. I don't know the theme, it might be good, but I wouldn't feel safe with it. There are plenty of free themes on http://wordpress.org/extend/themes.

Comment: Jason, I strongly recommend [only getting Themes from trusted sources](http://www.chipbennett.net/2010/12/10/only-download-wordpress-themes-from-trusted-sources/), such as the [official wordpress.org Theme directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes). Any Theme that obfuscates `functions.php` or any other Theme file or code should be dropped like a hot potato.